# Hough lines missing some lines

Tags: python, opencv, signal-processing, technical-indicator

I'm trying to detect lines in an irregular image using a relatively low `threshold` of 5. The result I get is the following:

[image]

where red lines are the computed lines. However, I was expecting the yellow lines to satisfy the parameters as well. Does anyone know why the yellow lines aren't detected? Here's my code:

```python
# img
rho = 1  # distance resolution in pixels of the Hough grid
theta = np.pi / 180  # angular resolution in radians of the Hough grid
threshold = 5  # minimum number of votes (intersections in Hough grid cell)
min_line_length = 200  # minimum number of pixels making up a line
max_line_gap = 500  # maximum gap in pixels between connectable line segments

low_threshold = 50
high_threshold = 150

edge_image = img.copy()
edge_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(edge_image, (3, 3), 1)
edges = cv2.Canny(edge_image, low_threshold, high_threshold)

line_image = np.copy(edges)  # creating a blank to draw lines on
line_image = cv2.cvtColor(line_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]),
                    min_line_length, max_line_gap)

for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(line_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),1)
```

Comment: context: in the beginning, it's stock data (the time series data was said to be available). the stock data was plotted with a thick brush. this image was then filtered and Canny'd. that is the image presented in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with the posted solution:

- `HoughLinesP` is applied on `img`: `lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img...`, when supposed to be applied on `edges`.
- Using `GaussianBlur` and `Canny` on an image with such "fine lines", is not recommender (the result is that each line is replicated twice).
  I recommend applying binary threshold and `dilate` (dilate with 2x2 kernel).
- `min_line_length = 200` is too long - the length of the short yellow line is about 120 pixels.
- We may better calibrate the parameters (`max_line_gap = 500` for example makes no sense).

---

Code sample:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('input_image_with_lines.png')  # Read image as BGR

# Apply threshold to each color channel for converting all the non-black pixels to white (needed to the usage of automatic threshold instead of manual threshold).
b_thres = cv2.threshold(img[:, :, 0], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # Apply automatic threshold to the blue channel
g_thres = cv2.threshold(img[:, :, 1], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # Apply automatic threshold to the green channel
r_thres = cv2.threshold(img[:, :, 2], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # Apply automatic threshold to the red channel
thres_image = b_thres | g_thres | r_thres  # thres_image is combined threshold images

#dilated_thres_image = cv2.dilate(thres_image, np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]], np.uint8))
dilated_thres_image = cv2.dilate(thres_image, np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8))  # Dilate thres_image with very small kernel - makes the lines thinker. 

# img
rho = 0.5  #1 distance resolution in pixels of the Hough grid
theta = np.pi / 180  # angular resolution in radians of the Hough grid
threshold = 5  # minimum number of votes (intersections in Hough grid cell)
min_line_length = 50 #200  # minimum number of pixels making up a line
max_line_gap = 2 #500  # maximum gap in pixels between connectable line segments

#low_threshold = 50
#high_threshold = 150

#edge_image = img.copy()
#edge_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(edge_image, (3, 3), 1)
#edges = cv2.Canny(edge_image, low_threshold, high_threshold)

#lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]),
#                    min_line_length, max_line_gap)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dilated_thres_image, rho, theta, threshold, None, min_line_length, max_line_gap)

line_image = cv2.cvtColor(dilated_thres_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) # creating a blank to draw lines on

for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        #cv2.line(line_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),1)
        cv2.line(line_image, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,0), 1)


# Display images for testing
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('thres_image', thres_image)
cv2.imshow('dilated_thres_image', dilated_thres_image)
cv2.imshow('line_image', line_image)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Output:
[image]

I realize that the result is not perfect, but we have to consider that Hough-Lines algorithm has its limitations...

Comment: I had him on IRC last night. teased one level of "source" imagery out of him. imagine the outline you see, but filled in. it's binary. it's also probably still not source data but filtered. -- true context: it's some stock chart data, that he drew with a wide brush or something, and now he's looking for straight-ish lines in that (in the drawn picture, not the actual stock data itself). stock brokers call this a "zig zag indicator"

Comment: I advised against canny and hough, or any _more_ filtering (that's what caused this mess). I recommended he try hough on the non-cannied image, because it still has some information to work with. OP's code however looks like that's just due to a typo, not intentional.